# Vim: Line Following Syntax Match is also a Syntax Match

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I would like to highlight lines matching this regex RED:

```
syn match RedLine "^\*\*\*  .*  \*\*\*\n"
```

Then I'd like to highlight the following line BLUE no matter what text it contains.

I tried using `\zs` to match the following line's pattern like this:

```
syn match BlueLine "^\*\*\*  .*  \*\*\*\n\zs.*"
```

But that doesn't work (my understanding is that the read position has passed the portion of the match before `\zs` already).

So I tried the "look behind" atom like this:

```
syn match BlueLine "\(^\*\*\*  .*  \*\*\*\n\)\@50<=.*"
```

But that was way too slow even with the 50 byte limit.

How can I always match an entire line whenever the previous line matches a certain pattern?

e.g.

```
***  this line's RED since it's surrounded by pairs of 3 stars  ***
this line's always BLUE because of the preceding line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to re-parse the first line to capture the second, following line (which indeed is highly inefficient). Vim has [`:help :syn-nextgroup`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-nextgroup), which directs the parser to continue parsing with preference to the specified group. The `skipnl` keyword skips over the newline in between. As you indiscriminately want to highlight the entire next line, a simple `.*` pattern will do. The only important detail for that rule is the `contained` keyword, so that this rule only matches triggered by the `nextgroup=`, but never on its own (which would color the entire buffer blue).

```
syn match RedLine "^\*\*\*  .*  \*\*\*$" skipnl nextgroup=BlueLine
syn match BlueLine ".*" contained
```